# Android Watch Face, "not compatible with this device". I'm missing something

Tags: android, wear-os

Ok, I recently started dabbling in Android development, and made a simple watch face. I don't own an Android watch (or any other Android device), so I'm using the emulator.

Well, the watch face works great through the emulator. So I put it up on Google Play, and asked a couple of friends to "beta" test it for me.

Unfortunately, none of them could get it working on their watches. They reported to me that they got the "not compatible" message, and therefore couldn't install the watch face.

I developed it under API 21 (Lollipop), using Android Studio. That could be one issue.

To be clear: When I set up the project, I only did it as a "wear" app, not as one you put on your phone, too. Perhaps that is another mistake on my part.

I've done a good bit of searching, and can't really find anything about what I need to do *in my code* to fix this, and I'm not really sure how to re-compile under a different SDK if that's what I need to do.

Any ideas on this?

EDIT:

Per request, here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<!-- Required to act as a custom watch face. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <service
        android:name=".MorseWatchFace"
        android:label="@string/my_digital_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_digital" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_digital_circular" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />

            <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: can you show the manifest.xml ?

Comment: @MathieuBertin added above.

Comment: @MathieuBertin Upon further review, it appears that my app is only compatible with about 19 devices. So I guess what I need is the ability to expand beyond that, so more people will DL the watch face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users are installing your apk from their phones (which they are, if they're using Google Play store on their phone), you must be uploading a phone APK.

Your wearable APK would only support roughly 19 devices, that makes sense -- that's about how many devices there are matching the criteria. Google Play will provide the APK to devices that have the same features defined (see https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html). So if you defined the wearable feature, it'll only target watches.

I recommend creating a new phone module. All it really needs is a basic manifest (just an `<application>` block) and a gradle dependency on your wearable module (e.g. add the line `wearApp project(':your-wearable-module')` to your phone module gradle file's dependencies block). Then just publish that module to Google Play. This phone apk will essentially just host your wearable apk inside of it, to allow it to be installed on phones.

Comment: I mostly follow what you're saying. But I'm a bit unclear. If I'm doing this specifically for watches, do I still need to do the mobile thing? if I'm reading what you're saying correctly, I do.

Comment: Yes. From https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html: *When publishing to users, you must package a wearable app inside of a handheld app, because users cannot browse and install apps directly on the wearable.*

Comment: This will change when Wear 2 comes out next year, but until then, follow the packaging instructions on that page.

Comment: @String Can I add the mobile piece after the fact and have it still work? My project works in the Watch emulator right now. So if I add the mobile piece to that project, should it work as described in the link you provided? I think I'm going to try that and see what happens.

Comment: @MJR should be fine, it doesn't matter what order you do it in. You just need to do the steps in that link.

Comment: @String thank you very much! I'll give that a shot and report back.

Comment: @String OK, I got the two apks like I was supposed to. Unfortunately, I can't get the mobile APK to appear on my mobile emulator now, so my concern is that if I publish it, no one will be able to download and use it.

Comment: What do you mean "can't get the mobile APK to appear on my mobile emulator"? Do you mean that the APK doesn't install? If so, what's the error message you're getting (either from adb or in logcat)?

Comment: @String well, it appears that Android Studio shows it installing. But when I look on the virtual device I don't see it. I've checked in downloads, installed apps, and a couple of other places. Let me check for an error. If I get one I will post it.

Comment: It won't be in downloads, and it'll only be in the app drawer if it has a launcher intent. Look for it in Settings > Apps, or run `adb shell pm list packages` and see if it's listed there.

Comment: @String: You're AWESOME! Is there any way I can award you points or something? My app doesn't have the launcher intent. That doesn't affect syncing with a watch, does it? If it doesn't, hopefully I can republish by the end of today. Thanks again for all your patience and help!

Comment: @String one more thing. I sent a friend of mine the newest APK via email attachment. He said he was unable to install it, and the only message he got was "app not installed". His devices are a Samsung Galaxy 7 and a 1st generation LG Urbane.

Comment: Having a launcher intent isn't required for the Wear packaging, though it is likely to confuse some users. Make sure you make it clear in your app description what the situation is. As for the S7 failure, it's tough to guess why that happened without seeing a log from the device.

Comment: Ok. So how would it sync with the watch? Would it do that automatically? What do I need to add to put a launch intent in it so I don't confuse users?

Comment: @MJR when you install an APK, there is a system packaging service that runs and does some work like unarchiving it, registering it as an installed package, etc. The user doesn't really know what's going on -- all users expect is that an icon appears somewhere. But with watch faces, there's nothing to launch -- I think what String is suggesting is that you make it clear to users (e.g. in your app's Google Play description) not to expect to have something to launch. This package manager service will extract your wear APK from your phone APK and copy it to any watches automatically

Comment: @MJR would be happy to test your APK if you're not shy about sharing it, or the code

Comment: @VasiliyKulakov let me post it, and I'll send you the link.